# Swift NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest

Tags: swift

In Objective C the following syntax was possible:

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
if ([response statusCode] == 404)
{
}
```

Now in Swift I have used:

```
var response : AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?> = nil
let urlData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: err)
```

which works, but I cannot access statusCode anymore, because if I use NSHTTPURLResponse it returns an error that NSURLResponse is needed!

Do you know any way to solve this?

Comment: Obviously, I hope you're never using `sendSynchronousRequest` from the main thread. One would always prefer asynchronous request (esp a cancelable one).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Instead of manually creating an `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer`, you can simply use `&` to wrap the value you want to send a pointer to - your code becomes much simpler:

```
var response: NSURLResponse?
var error: NSError?
let urlData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)
```

After the call, you need to cast your response to `NSHTTPURLResponse` to access those properties:

```
if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
    println(httpResponse.statusCode)
}
```