# Synchronous HTTP Requests in Swift

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift

Is it ok to wait for an asynchronous request (say an `NSURLSessionDataTask`,) using a semaphore for example.

There is a lot of advice out there claiming that synchronous networking is bad, however I don't see that as grounds for refusing synchronous *requests*, especially when they're done in a background thread.

Synchronous requests (in a background thread/queue) have the benefit of not needing to be callback-nested.

The answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31563134/466604 shows only a method to achieve this, but it comes with implied discouragement. (Along with other discouragement from https://devforums.apple.com/thread/9606?tstart=0)

My question is whether discouraging this discouragement is warranted, given those synchronous requests happen in a background thread, primarily as a way to avoid nesting callbacks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synchronous URL request on Swift 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557688/synchronous-url-request-on-swift-2)

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not ok. Don't do this.

iOS might even kill your app in the process. Besides, look at callbacks as they were the next step in your serial execution.

The processor needs those cycles to do other things, **don't be a bully**!

> **INSIGHT:**

As @EricD said, if your execution fails for some reason, that thread is lost until you exit your app and the O.S. claims it back.

> That thread is a valuable resource that must not be wasted and much
> more valuable in Mobile Operating Systems as iOS.

iPhone's processors are not as powerful as nowadays Desktop' processors or GPU's processors that can build up to hundreds of thousands threads.

If you use a **semaphore**, you are waking up to ask that thread after some time, and if the conditions has not being met, then you go to sleep again. This is usually in the ms time, but still, is some time that the processor dedicate to something useless.

> **MORE CLEAR**

When you define a callback, is as if you were to sleep and you say to somebody.

**Don't call me, I will call you when I'm ready to go.**

Instead, using a semaphore is like:

**Is ok if you call me 1000..0 times to ask me if I'm ready to go**

The overheading in this case is obvious...you usually needs a time to wake up and to sleep back again. **That's wasted processor time**

> Keep in mind that in the best case you are using a semaphore that put the Thread into sleep for a while, and then ask again if it is **OK** to proceed.
>
> If this is not the case, then this thread is using **ALL the processor cycles** assigned to it to ask you if it's ok to proceed, that is **100% CPU Usage in that Thread** evaluating **just** a condition.

Comment: This answer assumes that a parked thread (waiting on a semaphore) is a huge load on the system. I am unfamiliar with that notion.
If the execution fails, a value can be returned... Why does the thread need to be lost until app closes?

Comment: If you are doing an expensive operation in that thread, and happens that the thread hangs, or something weird happens, you will never receive that value and you will keep yourself asking if it's done in that same Thread. This will remain that Thread alive and busy and the OS will not be able to use it