# Asynchronous HTTP request - how do I know when ready ? swift 2

Tags: swift2

I'm building a class to retrieve METAR data (weather info) for certain location.
in class initializer im using swiftHTTP to make HTTP post request to retrieve XML with data.once I have the XML data I parse it and retrieve the temperature info and assigning it to class property.

The problem is that when I instantiate the class and try to access the temperature property it is still empty.

I know that its because the call is asynchronous , but how do I design this all correct so that after instantiating I can get the temperature property already with the retrieved value ?

Thanks

Yuval

Comment: would it be suit to you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557688/synchronous-url-request-on-swift-2

Comment: You should use a callback. I've got a few [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2227743+callback).