# Different DispatchQueue for different requests

Tags: ios, afnetworking, grand-central-dispatch, nsurlsession, nsoperationqueue

I want to have different priorities for different `http requests` and I want to be able to stop/pause some requests immediately and to execute only some of them if I have a request with `High` priority. I was going to use different approaches, but it seems that all of them are deprecated now:

1) To use `AFHTTPRequestOperation`, so I can create different `OperationQueue` base on `DispatchQueue` and add operations there, but it's deprecated in a new version of `AFNetworking`

2) To use different DispatchQueues with different priorities for different **Synchronous** requests (using `NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest`) (so I can stop some queues if I have highest priority operations and I can cancel operations immediately). But as far as I understand according to [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557688/synchronous-url-request-on-swift-2) , this way is deprecated, so I can't send a Synchronous request.

I understand that there are ways where Requests seem to be Synchronous using semaphores, but that's only an illusion, because all the requests will be executed in the queues I can't control.

**Are there any ways to control the `DispatchQueue` (or `OperationQueue`) where the request is executed?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should/could use `NSURLSessionTask/URLSessionTask` subclasses to grab data from the network. You could easily encapsulate them inside one `NSOperation/Operation` subclasses (see this [slide](https://speakerdeck.com/yageek/concurrency-on-darwin?slide=34).

You would just need to add cancellation support to it. You can find information about cancellation inside the **Responding to the Cancel Command** section of the [NSOperation documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperation).

To play with priorities you have several tools:

- To handle priorities between `OperationQueue` instances, you can attribute them different `qualityOfService` values.
- To handle priorities between `Operation` instances, you can attribute them different `qualityOfService`, `queuePriority` or `threadPriority` values.

Some additional explanation about those parameters can be found in the [Prioritize Work with Quality of Service Classes section](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/PrioritizeWorkWithQoS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015243-CH39-SW1) of the *Energy Efficiency Guide for iOS Apps*.